# Concurrent calls to setTimeout cause more delays than expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, express

I'm working on a small demo of Node performance and was surprised to see the following example with 50 concurrent calls to `setTimeout` take over 4 seconds instead of 500ms.

The following code sets up a very simple express server that listens for all requests, and responds 500ms later using `setTimeout`. Then it has a client that makes 50 requests passing in a number to track requests and corresponding responses.

```
// SERVER
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        return res.send(req.query.i);
    }, 500);
});

app.listen(8099);

// CLIENT
var http = require('http');

function start() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        console.log(new Date().getSeconds() + ':' + new Date().getMilliseconds() + ' - Sending ' + i);
        http.get('http://localhost:8099?i=' + i, responseHandler);
    }

    function responseHandler(res) {
        res.on('data', function (body) {
            return console.log(new Date().getSeconds() + ':' + new Date().getMilliseconds() + ' - Received ' + body);
        });
    }
}

start();
```

I expected the code to take 30-50ms to make all the `setTimeout` calls and then 500ms later all of them would respond around the same time. Instead I see them respond in groups of 5, with 500ms between each group of 5.

I tried a number of simpler alternatives which all do fix the problem. If I take the `setTimeout` out and immediately respond, all 50 responses come in within 100ms. If I take the web server out of the equation and just have 50 calls to `setTimeout`, then all 50 calls are queued immediately and all 50 come back at the same time 500ms later.

What could be causing the extra delays when express and http calls are combined with `setTimeout`?

Comment: You are experiencing those delays [because of the event queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822668/what-exactly-is-a-node-js-event-loop-tick).

Comment: I can confirm these findings.  Alex, that's not a helpful comment: *everything* asynchronous is related to the event queue.  Saying this is "because of the event queue" is like saying "it's because of programming".  Meaningless.  My suspicion is that the timer functions in Node have some kind of "meta queueing".  That is, in the timer queue, Node takes the next five available timers and schedules those for processing.  Not sure, though...looking at the Node source code now.

Comment: I take back what I said: I don't think it's a limitation of `setTimeout` (because, as Samuel said in his post, if you run this test without HTTP requests, it works as expected).  So this must be an HTTP/Express queue issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with `setTimeout` (as you might have guessed when you ran your test without the client/server setup).  The issue is the number of open HTTP sockets that a Node `http` server will handle at any given time.

The setting that controls this is `Agent.maxSockets` (see the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets) for more information).

The default value for `maxSockets` is five.  So if you send 50 requests to your app, it will process 5 of them at a time *until they complete* before moving on to new requests.  Since they can't complete until the `setTimeout` functions invoke their callbacks, you'll get your requests responded to in bursts of five approximately every 500 milliseconds.

If you want proof of this, all you have to do is change the value of `maxSockets`:

```
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 10;
```

Now you will see requests get processed in bursts of 10 instead.  If you set it to 50, you should see the behavior you're looking for.

Note that it's probably set to 5 for a pretty good reason, so I don't think the "solution" to your problem is just set `maxSockets` to `Infinity` or something terrifying like that.

mscdex points out in the comments that you can specify a cusotm agent in `http.request`, and also that there are going to be changes to the default `maxSockets` in Node v0.12.

Comment: A couple of notes: it should be made clearer that you can create a new/custom Agent instance that has its own `maxSockets` that you can pass to `http.request()` instead of mutating the default/global Agent's `maxSockets`. Also, the default/global Agent `maxSockets` is not going to be restricted (to 5) anymore with node v0.12.

Comment: Thanks for the info, mscdex.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Perfect. That fixed it. For my test I set it to 50. I understand the need for max sockets but 5 is very small, especially if you have an I/O intensive app where the majority of time is waiting on a lot of I/O or outside processes.

Comment: You can always use cluster, too, to spin up multiple instances.