# How many events can Node.js queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, message-queue, event-loop

From what I see, if an event in Node take a "long time" to be dispatched, Node creates some kind of "queue of events", and they are triggered as soon as possible, one by one.

How long can this queue be?

Comment: I don't think there's a limit but your RAM.

Comment: I believe events are actually always queued.

Comment: I don't think this is how the event queue is handled

Answer (score 36, accepted):

While this may seem like a simple question, it is actually a rather complex problem; unfortunately, there's no simple number that anyone can give you.

First: wall time doesn't really play a part in anything here.  All events are dispatched in the same fashion, whether or not things are taking "a long time."  In other words, all events pass through a "queue."

Second: there is no single queue.  There are many places where different kinds of events can be dispatched into JS.  (The following assumes you [know what a tick is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19823583/201952).)

- There are the things you (or the libraries you use) pass to `process.nextTick()`.  They are called at the end of the current tick until the nextTick queue is empty.
- There are the things you (or the libraries you use) pass to `setImmediate()`.  They are called at the start of the next tick.  (This means that `nextTick` tasks can add things to the current tick indefinitely, preventing other operations from happening whereas `setImmediate` tasks can only add things to the queue for the next tick.)
- I/O events are handled by [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv) via `epoll`/`kqueue`/IOCP on Linux/Mac/Windows respectively.  When the OS notifies libuv that I/O has happened, it in turn invokes the appropriate handler in JS.  A given tick of the event loop may process zero or more I/O events; if a tick takes a long time, I/O events will queue in an *operating system* queue.
- [Signals](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) sent by the OS.
- Native code (C/C++) executed on a separate thread may invoke JS functions.  This is usually accomplished through the [libuv work queue](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/threads.html#libuv-work-queue).

Since there are many places where work may be queued, [it is not easy to answer "how many items are currently queued"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/vsgt4jJ7YUk), much less what the absolute limit of those queues are.  Essentially, the hard limit for the size of your task queues is available RAM.

In practice, your app will:

- Hit V8 heap constraints
- For I/O, max out the number of allowable open file descriptors.

...well before the size of any queue becomes problematic.

If you're just interested in whether or not your app under heavy load, [toobusy](https://github.com/lloyd/node-toobusy) may be of interest -- it times each tick of the event loop to determine whether or not your app is spending an unusual amount of time processing each tick (which may indicate that your task queues are very large).

Comment: Wow, what an amazing answer. Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 3):

Handlers for a specific event are called synchronously (in the order they were added) *as soon as the event is emitted*, they are not delayed at all.

The total number of event handlers is limited only by v8 and/or the amount of available RAM.

Comment: if ram limit is reached, will node pause scheduling additional events until more memory frees up or will the VM simply terminate?  I'm trying to understand whether this is the cause of my [OOM problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36492268/nodejs-running-out-of-memory-processing-csv-files/36493158?noredirect=1#comment60612338_36493158)

Comment: @DmitryB. If v8 cannot allocate any more memory and attempts to GC enough space fails, it will die, just like most any other program.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're talking about operations that can take an undefined amount of time to complete, such as an http request or filesystem access.

Node gives you a method to complete these types of operations asynchronously, meaning that you can tell node, or a 3rd party library, to start an operation, and then call some code (a function that you define) to inform you when the operation is complete. This can be done through event listeners, or callback functions, both of which have their own limitations.

With event listeners the maximum amount of listeners you can have is dependent on the maximum array size of your environment. In the case of node.js the javascript engine is v8, but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154989/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-javascript) there is a maximum set out by the 5th ECMA standard of ~4billion elements, which is a limit that you shouldn't ever overcome.

With callbacks the limitation you have is the max call stack size, meaning how deep your functions can call each other. For instance you can have a callback calling a callback calling a callback calling another callback, etc etc. The call stack size dictates how may callbacks calling callbacks you can have. Note that the call stack size can be a limitation with event listeners as well as they're essentially callbacks that can be executed multiple times.

And these are the limitations with each.

Comment: Re event listeners, the array size is the limit on the number of listener *callback functions* listening for events, not the limit on the size of the queue holding events to be dispatched.  Also, call stack limits can be worked around via `setImmediate`/`process.nextTick`.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no "queue" of events waiting to be dispatched. When `dispatchEvent` or `emit` or similar function is called, all the listeners for that event get called before `dispatchEvent` returns. Granted you can have nested event dispatching, where an event listener can dispatch another event, but there's still no "queuing" going on. Although that's my experience with events. There may be some mechanism that node uses to reset the call stack that uses a queue? But how I described it is generally how events work.

Comment: Also, yes, the array size limit is the limit on the number of listeners you can have for one event type.

Comment: What you're describing is how `EventEmitter` (the JavaScript module) works, and is generally true for how user code (JS) emits events.  However, the native side, there are several different types of queues as I [describe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34144953/201952).

Comment: I figured that's what we're talking about since this has a javascript tag. Your answer is very interesting to me though as I haven't delved much into the native side of node.