# nodejs running out of memory processing csv files

Tags: javascript, node.js, out-of-memory

I've read through a number of SO questions about nodejs running out of memory, but I haven't seen anything that sounds similar to my situation.

I'm trying to process about 20GBs of data across 250 csv files (so ~80MBs/file).  Launch the node script with `--max-old-space-size=8192` on a server with 90GB of free memory using node v5.9.1.  After 9mins of processing the script quits with an out-of-memory error.

I'm new to Node programming, but I thought I wrote the script to process data one line at a time and not to keep anything in memory.  Yet it seems some object references are being held on to by something, so the script is leaking memory.  Here's the full script:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://buzzard/xtra');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

var DeviceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    serial: String
});

var Device = mongoose.model('Device', DeviceSchema, 'devices');

function processLine(line) {
    var serial = line.split(',')[8];

    Device({
        _id: serial,
        serial: serial
    }).save(function (err) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
    });
}

function processFile(baseDir, fileName) {
    if(!fileName.startsWith('qcx3'))
        return;

    var fullPath = `${baseDir}/${fileName}`;

    var lineReader = readline.createInterface({
      input: fs.createReadStream(fullPath)
    });

    lineReader.on('line', processLine);
}

function findFiles(rootDir) {
  fs.readdir(rootDir, function (error, files) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`Error: ${error}` );
        return
    }

    files.forEach(function (file) {
        if(file.startsWith('.'))
            return;

        var fullPath = `${rootDir}/${file}`;

        fs.stat(fullPath, function(error, stat) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(`Error: ${error}` );
                return;
            }

            if(stat.isDirectory())
                dir(fullPath);
            else
                processFile(rootDir, file);
        });
    });
  })
}  


findFiles('c://temp/logs/compress');
```

I also noticed that when I run the script on a much smaller test set that it can completely finish processing, the script doesn't exit at the end.  Just keeps hanging there until I ctrl+c it.  Could this be somehow related?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've been thinking, since everything down to a line in the csv file is executed asynchronously, is it possible there is simply an explosion of events in the event loop that overwhelms the system?  If so, how do I throttle async events?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?  I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @easymoden00b: I had found the cause, but my solution then was to rewrite this in python.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504949/throttling-events-in-event-queue

Answer (score 0):

1. The script is not exiting cause you have an open connection to mongoose, after all the files has been processed you should close the connection and the script will finish.
2. You have the right Idea of using streams but i think you missed something on the way, I suggest you the following article to update the streamInterface, and events. https://coderwall.com/p/ohjerg/read-large-text-files-in-nodejs
3. An other source of problem could be the mongodb, it seems you make a lot of inserts, it could be related with the max i/o of mongodb that exhaust the memory.

Comment: 1) if I understand asynchronous nature of node correctly, writes to the db may continue long after the last file is processed; 2) I don't see anything different from what I am doing in that link; 3) yeh, I've been thinking of how to utilize the new Bulk API.

Comment: 2) I didn't see the stream part in your code, but I am more inclined to 3) cause of the problem

Comment: since each line is processed asynchronously, is it possible that the system is simply overwhelmed with the number of events created in node's event queue?  What would be throttling the size of the queue?  There are millions of lines.

Comment: It could be you can try the `async.queue` method to test it has an concurrence parameter you can play with it