# throttling events in event queue

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a [recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36492268/nodejs-running-out-of-memory-processing-csv-files), I outlined an OOM condition that I'm running into while processing a large number of csv files with millions of records in each.

The more I am looking into the problem and the more I'm reading up on Node.js the more convinced I become that the OOM isn't happening because of a memory leak but because I'm not throttling the data input into the system.

The code just blindly sucks in all data, creating a single callback event for each line.  The events keep getting added to the main event loop, which eventually becomes so large that it exhausts all available memory.

What are Node's idiomatic patterns for dealing with this scenario?  Should I be tying reading of csv files to a blocking queue of some sort that, once full, will block the file reader from parsing more of the data?  Are there any good examples dealing with processing of large data sets?

---

**Update**: To put this differently and simpler, Node can process input faster than it can process output and the slack is being stored in memory (queued as events for the event queue).  Because there is a lot of slack, the memory eventually gets exhausted.  So the question is: what's the idiomatic way of throttling down input to the output's rate?

Comment: Sharing some sample code would help me do a more specific example, if my answer doesn't provide enough detail.

Comment: the code is linked in the very first sentence. Thanks.

Comment: My mistake, I'm used to seeing the relevant code in the question being asked about it.  I'll update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to set things up as streams, and rely on the built-in backpressure semantics to do so.  The [Streams Handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) as a really good overview on it.

> Similar to unix, the node stream module's primary composition operator is called .pipe() and you get a backpressure mechanism for free to throttle writes for slow consumers.

**Update**

I've not used the `readline` module for anything other than a terminal input before, but reading the docs it looks like it accepts an input stream and an output stream.  If you frame your DB writer as a writeable stream, you should be able to let `readline` pipe it for you internally.

Comment: Ah!  Things are starting to click in place for me...  I did use a stream for reading data, but I didn't use a pipe.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm going to switch from readline to [node-csv](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv), which implements streams.  On the other end, I see there are at least a couple of libraries ([mongoose-object-stream](https://tonicdev.com/npm/mongoose-object-stream) and [mongoose-write-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-write-stream)) that implement writable streams on top of Mongoose.  Thanks for setting me in the right direction.