# Does nextTick means next phase in Node.js (Event Loop)?

Tags: node.js, v8, event-loop, libuv

What does `process.nextTick` exactly mean ?

Does `nextTick` mean, after callback queue pop for one element in the current phase ? Or before moving to the next phase after executing all callbacks in the current phase's queue ?

Answer (score 0):

This is described in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_arg).

`nextTick` queues callbacks to be invoked at the end of the current tick.  The entire queue is emptied before moving to the next tick.

Contrast with [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args), which queues callbacks to be invoked during the **next** tick.

(Yes, the names are misleading, but their behavior is that way to keep compatibility.)

Comment: setImmediate, during the next tick ! or just in the check phase of the event loop ?