How can I get the final committed state of React component in the setState final callback?
I have some very concurrent situation where the state of the app is changed in response to many different events that happen concurrently, so the classic setState(state) doesn't work, and I have to use setState(state => { return {...state + extra } }) which works on the uncommitted state (it means other events can add alterations to it before it is used for the next re-render), but at the same time I need to return some results back via a promise WHEN THE STATE IS COMMITTED (after all concurrent changes have been applied to it), so I go:
function applyChangesToState(param1, param2) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.setState(state => {
            // some compuations here
            const extra = calculateSomeExtra(state, param1, param2);
            return {...state, extra };
        , () => {
            // HOW CAN I ACCESS THE COMMITED (MOST RECENT AND FINAL) STATE HERE?
            const { extra } = state; // <-- WHERE SHOULD I READ THE COMMITTED STATE FROM?
            // SO I CAN PUT IT IN RESOLVE:
            resolve(extra);

            // IF I READ FROM this.state HERE IS IT CERTAIN THAT 
            // ALL CONCURRENT CHANGES HAVE BEEN APPLIED ALREADY PRIOR TO
            // THE NEXT RE-RENDER?
        });
    });
}


Basically my question is How, by initiating a state change, can I get the most final state prior to it being sent to re-render via a callback?
UPDATE:
So the answer is: use this.state in the final callback!

Sounds like you want state debouncing, instead.

Remember that React is a user interface framework. Your component's props and state are the only authorities when it comes to what data is available for the current render pass: only change them when the user needs to see something new, not blindly "when you have new data" =)
In this case, you absolutely don't want to update state just because you data sources pushed new data your way, you want to track all those changes outside of React, so you can update your component state only as fast as makes sense for humans to see.
For example:
export class Debouncer() {
  state = {};
  lastRun = 0;

  constructor(initialState, setState, interval = 500) {
    this.setState = setState;
    this.interval = interval;
    this.update(initialState);
  }

  update(data) {
    // commit the change in this debouncer and reset the debounce timer
    clearTimeout(this.debounce);
    Object.assign(this.state, data);

    // Then check if we need to trigger a setState now, or later:
    const now = Date.now();
    const delta = now - this.lastRun;
    if (delta > this.interval) {
      return this.send();
    } else {
      this.debounce = setTimeout(
        () => this.send(),
        this.interval
      );
    }
  }

  send() {
    this.lastRun = Date.now();
    this.setState(this.state);
  }
}

And then you import that and use that as your data handler, rather than overloading setState with data.
import { useState } from "react";
import { Debouncer } from "./wherever.js";

export function MyComponent(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const debouncer = new Debouncer(state, setState, 250);
    
    // even if this thing generates updates every millisecond,
    // our component isn't going to update every millisecond,
    // because we're not updating the component state, we're
    // updating the debouncer state.
    highFrequencyUpdatingAPI.realtime.listen(
      `stock price updates or whatever`,
      (data) => debouncer.update(data)
    );
  }, []);

  return <div>{things based on state}</div>;
}


debounce of 250 will make everything significantly slower, basically yes, why won't i reimplement the state management? because it's already implemented in React all i need is to find a way to use it

No, it won't. Because four updates a second is nonsense for almost anything that isn't real time data visualization. And if that's what you need: why on earth are you using React instead of a WS-backed canvas (or well designed SVG with CSS transforms)? Don't use a hammer to drive in a screw just because you already have a hammer.

look, i've been working with UI a lot, even 50 ms is already noticeable, and as for SVG and Canvas, yes we use them a lot, it's a whole different beast and takes some special skills

As you know, JavaScript runs the program in a single thread, therefore there is no inherent concurrently in it. When it starts executing an event, it does not stop until it finishes the event. Therefore events cannot run concurrently.
As a result, the states cannot be updated concurrently as well.
Even in the cases of using asynchronous calls or Worker threads, the main thread only has the direct access to the states. The results from asynchronous calls and Worker threads have to be communicated through the main thread to get the states updated. Therefore no concurrent state updates in such cases as well.
Besides that, React does not batch state updates across intentional events. It batches state updates whenever it is safe to do. This ensures that, for example, if the first button click disables a form, the second click would not submit it again. This can be read from here : React batches state updates
Therefore the real difference between a updater function and an expression or "replace with value" comes only when there are multiple or a series of state updates in a single same event. If there is a series of state updates in the same single event, then a updater function is required to get the intended result, otherwise an expression would do the same job.
Based on the above points, the answer to the question may be to compute locally the series of state updates in the event. This manual computation should yield the same result of the state in the subsequent render. You may be able to refer to a similar Q&A here: Before function flow is not finished yet and setState update is not done, get latest state for debugging purpose

Hi, Thank you for your vote, as this site requests, I also request you to leave your valuable feedback in addition to your vote, so that it will help me to improve this post.

say i run an asyn operation triggered by one event, and another async operation triggered by another event, there is no way to say which one will finish first and which will or will not happen before React finalizes the changes to the state, hence concurrent setup, yes i know about the single thread compartment but nonetheless there is a single resource and a number of parties who want to modify it, a racing condition is a better way to put it

Thank you for your comments and the clarifications. The purpose of this comment is just to bring up the point that race condition is impossible in JavaScript. You are right on the point - There is a single resource and a number of parties to modify the same. In JavaScript, there are two important things to take care each of them -  an event loop and the event queue(s). continues...

The sync as well as async functions are queued always. This simplifies the situation in the first level. And in the second level, this event queue is processed by the event loop synchronously - not asynchronously, since event loop itself is single-threaded - it can do only one thing at a time. This completes the scenarios that there is no chance of a race condition in JavaScript. The answer in the following post is taking about the same in detail : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822668/what-exactly-is-a-node-js-event-loop-tick

look, racing conditions in javascript happen all the time, basically any time you have 2 async calls without await, you create a racing condition (because 2 async operations are triggered and you don't know which is going to end first)

Thank you for your comment. I have taken note of it. It adds value to me.
